# Increasing suction air flow with multiple pumps

Tags: pressure, vacuum, vacuum-pumps

I'm trying to build a small pick and place system using a suction cup and a 12V vacuum pump. The problem I'm having is that I'm not getting a good enough seal between the cup and the object, and I read that it could be improved by increasing airflow. I've also read that placing pumps in parallel can increase airflow, but is there a limit to the number of pumps that can be placed in parallel? Would the pumps overheat as a result of using too many pumps in parallel? The pump I'm using has a datasheet vacuum pressure of -0.08Mpa and an airflow of 16L/min. The pump itself is composed of 2 pumps in parallel.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: 16l/min ~= 0.25l/second is not vast. You can buy pumps with far larger capacities at relatively reasonable cost. I suggest that you at least look at bigger pumps while looking at more pumps. I don't know what country you are in. I've looked on ebay in a number of countries in recent months for pumps of rather larger capacities than you are dealing with - there are often some very well priced used units available.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I get what you're saying, but large 12V/24V DC pumps seem hard to come by though. The large ones I've seen are all AC. I'm in Australia, but I don't mind buying overseas if needed.